# 'HttpRequest.h' file not found in Android, works in iOS (Cocos2dx)

Tags: android, eclipse, cocos2d-x

I am working in Eclipse on a Cocos2dx project.  I have it compiling for iOS just fine, but when I try to compile for Android in Eclipse I get the error

```
In file included from jni/../../Classes/GoodbyeWorldScene.cpp:1:
jni/../../Classes/GoodbyeWorldScene.h:7:10: fatal error: 'HttpRequest.h' file
  not found
```

So, looking at Line 1 of GoodbyeWorldScene.cpp, I have

```
#include "GoodbyeWorldScene.h"
```

And in GoodbyeWorldScene.h I have:

```
#include "HttpRequest.h"
#include "HttpClient.h"
```

I have tried it both with quotes and with <>

I have tried including in my Android.mk file

```
           ../../cocos2d/cocos/network/HttpRequest.h \
```

It appears the only solution is to add it directly into my list of classes, even though it should be a part of the Cocos standard library.  What's that all about?  Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the official way is to add the declaration of 'HttpRequest.h' in the Android.mk. So I think your solution is correct.